# Css3 calc function : issue with mod operator

Tags: html, css, calc

I'm using :
width:calc(100% mod 320);
but it always returns the full width of the parent element.
Seemingly nothing's wrong with the syntax it looks like a support issue.
Tested on chrome 37 and firefox 32.0.
Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p5nwqgob/1/)

```
<div class="mod">test2</div><!-- it should be 100px -->
.mod{
    width:calc(300px mod 200);
}
```

Comment: Can't see `mod` as an operator in [the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/). Maybe it was present in initial recommendation and was dropped (or) is a new feature which is not supported anywhere. Not found in [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc) also.

Comment: +1 - I never knew about the mod operator. Thanks

Comment: yes you're right apparently it was dropped i found it in an older [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/2006/WD-css3-values-20060919/#calc) thanks @Harry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) It looks like only IE supports the mod operator and it does function as you thought.

2) You need to add `px` on the units of the modulo (as C-link mentioned)

3) As @Harry mentioned, [the current spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#calc-notation) has dropped the mod operator from the calc function

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/p5nwqgob/5/)** - (try it on Internet explorer)

### Sample markup -

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="no">no calc</div>
    <div class="simple">simple</div>
    <div class="mod1">mod1</div>
    <div class="mod2">mod2</div>
    <div class="mod3">mod3</div>
    <div class="mod4">mod4</div>
</div>
```

### CSS (test cases)

```
.container {
    width: 450px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
.no {
   background:aqua; 
}
.simple {
    width:calc(100% - 100px);
    background:green;
}
.mod1 {
    width:calc(100% mod 200px); /* = 450 % 200 = 50px */
    background:red;
}
.mod2 {
    width:calc(100% mod 300px); /* = 450 % 300 = 150px */
    background:brown;
}
.mod3 {
    width:calc(100% mod 50px); /* = 450 % 50 = 0 */
    background:orange;
}
.mod4 {
    width:calc(50% mod 100px); /* = 225 % 100 = 25px */
    background:yellow;
}
```

Comment: +1, suprisingly ie does some thing, but always outsized hhhhhhhhhhh

Answer (score -2):

25% mod 2 (The remainder of 25% divided by 2)

Useful link for you, Learn to use this function. [**How-to use the Calc Function in CSS3**](http://www.binvisions.com/tutorials/calc-function-css3-introduction/)

**CSS**

```
.mod{
    width: calc(300px - ((300px / 200) * 200));
    background:red;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/hamix/c4bqctas/)

Comment: your answer is what i've just posted above i used that formula : 25% mod 2 or 300px mod 200 is the same formula. but your exemple was about the division operator which is not the subject thanks anyway

Comment: I tried all the methods for calculating the remaining. But none of it worked.It can be manually calculate.You can try this way.``width: calc(300px - ((300px / 200) * 200));``

Comment: the mod operator can't be simulated mathematically unless there is a truncation function to eliminate the decimales (which doesn't exist in css). So your equation gives always 0 as result. that's why i'll do it in js ;)