# How to incrementally resize div with browser window?

Tags: html, css

I have a div that I'm trying to make incrementally wider as the browser window is resized. That is, for every 50px wider the window is, I'd like the div's width to increase by 50px as well.

Since the width is in increments, I can't define it in terms of percentages. Right now I'm using media queries, but in order to make that work, I've had to write a ton of similar cases and it behaves inconsistently in different browsers.

I can't edit the JavaScript. Is there a more programmatic way I can do this in pure CSS?

[Here's my code.](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bdNGwG)

```
div {
  background-color: #f00;
  height: 100px;
}

@media (max-width: 1600px) {
  div {
    width: 800px;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 1550px) {
  div {
    width: 750px;
  }
}

/* ... */

@media (max-width: 800px) {
  div {
    width: 0;
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you provide your HTML and CSS code which you have tried

Comment: I've added it to the original post.

Answer (score 1):

Well there's some good news and some bad news. The good news is that there is a mod operator which could be used to do incremental sizes:

```
width: calc(500px + (100% mod 50px) * 50px);
```

The bad news, however, is that this isn't fully supported by all browsers. From what I've read around the internet, [internet explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25709194/css3-calc-function-issue-with-mod-operator) and [firefox](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2010/06/css3-calc/) kinda support it, but I couldn't get it working on safari/webkit, even when using the -webkit prefix.

Edit: after poking around some more, [mod used to be in the specification back in 2006](http://www.w3.org/TR/2006/WD-css3-values-20060919/#calc) but [as of 2013 it's been dropped :(](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/)

Comment: Sorry, I should have clarified. The div's width would be in multiples of 50px, and at any given window size, it would be the largest multiple that would still fit in the parent element.

Comment: @Himbeyer89 I updated my answer with the modulus function, it may be worth checking out