# Is there any way to resize css elements in increments / multiples of a particular number?

Tags: css

I'd like any div element to resize when the viewport size changes, so generally I could use e.g. flex or `10em` or `%` - but actually I'd like it only to resize in increments of 30 pixels, so it'd always align with a background.

Is this possible?

The only way I could think of is defunct - it might have been possible with the `mod` operator back in the day but not now?

[Using modulus in css calc function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34435330/using-modulus-in-css-calc-function)

Also I could achieve this with media queries but to set that up for increments of only 30 pixels would be a nightmare.

The snippet below has a max-width of 210px and a min-width of 30px. As the browser resizes from wide to thin, it should jump in increments of 30px only.

```css
.Mlt{
   background-color:grey;
   min-width:60px;
   max-width:210px;
}
```

```html
<div class="Mlt">
    <p>Hello</p>
    <p>Content</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you provide a snippet?

Comment: I put in a very basic snippet and I do mean basic, because I don't know where to begin tbh.

Comment: _"as the browser resizes from wide to thin, it should jump in increments of 30px only."_ When do you expect the increase/decrease in size? You say as the browser sizes, but you don't give any parameters. You could use `media queries` for the break point you expect it to increase/decrease.

Comment: As I said in the question I thought I could use media queries but I think for a full screen this would be tens and tens of them, not really optimal. I found a similar question with the `mod` answer here but it's old. I was hoping there was another way to this other than media queries. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29857411/how-to-incrementally-resize-div-with-browser-window

Comment: Oh and the decrease in size is always the widest possible - It'd snap to the largest width that was a multiple of 30px each time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

CSS grid can do this but you will need an extra container. The trick is to create columns having `30px` of width using `auto-fit` then you simply span all the created columns:

<sub>The use of jquery is only for demo purpose to show the width on resize. I also removed the max-width to easily test</sub>

```js
console.log($('.Mlt > div').width());
$(window).resize(function() {
  console.log($('.Mlt > div').width());
})
```

```css
.Mlt {
  min-width: 60px;
  display:grid;
  grid-template-columns:repeat(auto-fit,30px);
  /* justify-content: center; <-- use this if you want to center the div */
}

.Mlt > div {
  grid-column:1/-1; /* take all the columns */
  background-color: grey;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="Mlt">
  <div >
    <p>Hello</p>
    <p>Content</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not what I'd call easy on the eyes, but, this is the best solution I could come up with:

```js
const div = document.querySelector('.Mlt');

window.addEventListener('resize', () => {
  if (div.clientWidth >= window.innerWidth - 20) {
    div.style.width = div.clientWidth - 30 + "px";
  } else if (div.clientWidth < window.innerWidth - 20) {
    div.style.width = div.clientWidth + 30 + "px";
  }

  // Display div width
  document.getElementById('div-width').innerHTML = div.style.width;
})
```

```css
.Mlt {
  background-color: grey;
  min-width: 60px;
  max-width: 510px;
}
```

```html
<div class="Mlt">
  <p>Hello</p>
  <p>Content</p>
</div>

<!-- Display div width -->
<div id="div-width"></div>
```

Relies on JS if that's what you're after. With CSS I don't see any other way than setting an unreasonable number of media queries, like you said.

The `div`s width increases and decreases by multiples of 30 when it hits the edge of the viewport. I've set minus 30 on `window.innerWidth` as that's what it needed in JSFiddle's preview window, you might need to tweak it a bit.

You can test it here: https://jsfiddle.net/L61sq3fd/1/

Comment: I was hoping for css-only but I did consider that it'd only be possible with some JS sprinkles. Upvoted because it works and I'm trying both answers to see what feels best.

Comment: Other answer is definitely better than mine!

Comment: Yeah it's working very well, I extended it to 25px rows too and basically have an isometric grid background with items that snap into place no matter what size the window!